# Convert a column's value when displaying in an Edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, partials

So, my subject line isn't doing my question justice, but here is what i need:

I have a price field in my Product model.

Here is the form field I use, it's just a normal form field:

```
<%= f.label :price, "Price: Use numbers and a decimal only. E.g., 34.00" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :price, :style => "width: 50px" %>
```

I convert this decimal into an integer before i save it in the database, this is because I have to do some math later on with it, and well Integers are easier to add then dealing with float math.

However, when a user goes to Edit this field again, it comes up as an Integer or `3400` in the text field.

How do i tell `f.text_field` to display the float value instead?

My google fu is off, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: what data type is price in the database?

Comment: Integer is the data type.  Float isn't designed for math, and I guess I'll try my luck with Integer math this time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= f.text_field :price, :value => @product.price.to_f %>`

Comment: damn it, that was easy. totally overlooked that.  To reuse the form field, i just modified it to `<%= f.text_field :price, :value => (@product.price.to_f unless @product.new_record?) %>`  To clean it up I'll put that in the helper too, but anyways, that is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep the data in the database as the user entered it for this reason.  Could you add another column that represents the integer value to be used for the later Math?

Comment: I can't select yours as the official answer, but I used your approach to help me out of the jam, but Greg's actually displayed it properly.  So in other words, I created an `attr_accessor :input_price`, and converted that to my price in the DB as an integer, and then in the views i deconvert_price, where i probably should have that logic, as in my app, behind the scenes it's always an integer, but in the 'front' of the app, they see the float.